# How to match a URL pattern for a chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to match on a URL pattern to have my content script run against. The http:// pattern matches, but if I go to the same site, minus the http://, it doesn't run. How do I indicate that I want the plugin to run even if the http:// is missing.

Here is my mainfest:

```
    {
  "name": "BrowserExtension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description" : "Description ...",
  "icons": { "16": "icons/16x16.png", "48": "icons/48x48.png", "128": "icons/128x128.png" },

  "omnibox": { "keyword" : "yeah" },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/19x19.png",
      "38": "icons/38x38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "That's the tool tip",
    "default_popup": "browseraction/popup.html"
  },

  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "newtab/newtab.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout"],
      "js": ["content.js", "jquery.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/*"],
      "js": ["cart.js", "jquery.js"]        
    }
  ],

   "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],

  "devtools_page": "devtools/devtools.html"
}
```

When I go to this page, the javascript doesn't run:

```
http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/supreme-pink-panther-denim-shirt
```

Comment: post your manifest file please

Comment: How about this? `"matches": ["http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/*", "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/*"],`

Comment: I've wrote a simple extension with your manifest. And the injected script was executed as expected when I visit //www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/supreme-pink-panther-denim-shirt. The pattern will match either http or https when you put "*" in scheme. What will your content script do? Try to remove all logic and print string in the console log to check if the script is executed or not.